# What variable will be chosen if I use anonymous functions?

Tags: haskell

```
  findSatisfying :: (Int -> Bool) -> Int -> Int -> Bool
  findSatisfying p from to =
  divideAndConquer
  (\(x,y) -> x >= y)

  (\(x,y) -> x==y && p x)

  (\(x,y) -> ((x,x+((y-x) `div` 2)) , ((x+(y-x) `div` 2)+1,y))) 

  (||)

  (from, to)
```

This is a function to find an Interger in a List which satifies the function p which is in the form(Int->Bool).

Furthermore its using anonymous functions with (x,y) -> ... which correspond to "from" and "to".

I am not sure why they correspond to "from" and "to" however and not to "p".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The parameters of an anonymous function, just like the parameters of named a function, will take whichever values the function is applied to. So if the parameters of your anonymous functions take on the values `from` and `to`, it's because `divideAndConquer` applies them to those values.